# itemize doesn't work in IPE

Tags: lists, itemize

I want to use itemized lists in IPE. Everytime when I try to do this I get following error:

```
 Assertion failed on line #511 (ipegeo.cpp): 't != 0'
 Aborted (core dumped)
```

I've read that itemize environments need a box where paragraphs are allowed(e.g. minipage or parbox). But even when I have the itemize environment in a minipage it doesn't work.
Does anyone know how I can fix the error?

edit: I have Ubuntu 12.04, Tex Live 2012 and IPE 7

Comment: I cannot reproduce that.  I can use itemize just fine, both by choosing the "itemize" type of paragraph text, and by inserting itemize environment into a paragraph text.  Can you give more details (platform, version, ...)?

Comment: @JanHlavacek: I think I found out what causes the problems, but I don't know how to fix it. If I use the usual stylesheets (basic, standard, presentation) I can use itemize but if I use my own stylesheet it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Hm, it seems like a bug, no matter what stylesheet you use, it should not crash the program. You should file a bug report at http://sourceforge.net/apps/mantisbt/ipe7/main_page.php.  Attach the stylesheet that causes the problem.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipe_%28software%29 Too localised, unclear.